# ASP.NET routing behind an API management service

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, routes, azure-api-management

Whilst it's not the nicest thing in the world, I have a setup where I have a handful of web apps listed as APIs in an API Management Service in Azure.

I've noticed that a call like `Html.ActionLink` generates a URL based on the web app URL, rather than the *actual* URL being used by the APIM.

For example, if I have a web app called "example-web-app" the URL produced by `Html.ActionLink` might be

```
https://example-web-app/Home/Index
```

But if I'm calling it through APIM, my start URL will be

```
https://somedomain.com/examplewebapp
```

Is there a way to force calls like `Html.ActionLink` to produce a custom URL? Or would this need to be a generic setting for the entire web app?

**Edit: Turns out there was a caching issue. However, setting the API URL suffix causes the following:**

URL:

```
https://somedomain.com/examplewebapp/Home/Index
```

`Html.ActionLink` generated URL:

```
https://somedomain.com/Home/Index
```

Comment: can you please tell me what you are trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`redirect-content-urls` policy was created with this scenario in mind: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/api-management/redirect-content-urls-policy It will try to replace your API's backend URLs in response with APIM's frontend URL. If it proves to be too rigid for your scenario, regular `find-and-replace-policy` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/find-and-replace-policy) could also be used.